# Is this correct sort method?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Is this correct method to sort ArrayList?
The problem is that the list is not sorted.

```
out = new StringTokenizer(input.toString());
n = (out.countTokens());
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    String[] words = { out.nextToken().toString() };
    final List<String> wordList = Arrays.asList(words);
    Collections.sort(wordList);
    System.out.println(wordList.toString());
}
```

Comment: Why don't you move the sort to outside the loop?

Comment: @Maroun Maroun By alphabyte

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each of your `words[]` arrays is composed of a single string, obtained from the next token of your StringTokenizer. And you are iterating in exact order of the tokenization. So yes, your output will ***not*** be sorted. I presume you wanted to do something like this:

```
out = new StringTokenizer(input.toString());
int count = out.countTokens():
List<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>(count);
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    wordList.add(out.nextToken());
}
Collections.sort(wordList);
```

***But***, don't use the tokenizer class, its legacy. The following code will serve you better:

```
List<String> wordList = Arrays.asList(input.split("\\s"));
Collections.sort(wordList);
```

Comment: Can you tell me, how to fix it?

Comment: @antoxa2584 - I was editing in some code. See updated answer.

Comment: And if i need to sort it by second char, for examlpe, how i can do it?

Comment: That would be a custom sort - you would need to create a Comparator<String> with the logic, and use it in `Collections.sort(wordList, myCustomComparator)`.

Comment: I try this, but it dosnt work at all

`Collections.sort(wordList, new Comparator<String>() {public int compare(String o1, String o2) {return compare(Character.toString(o1.charAt(1)), haracter.toString(o2.charAt(1)));} });`

Comment: Hmmm, you should probably post this as a separate question, code in comments doesn't work well. But, first of all you need to validate that both strings are size 2 in length or greater, and handle the case where one or both is not. Then, if both are valid, just do `o1.substring(1, 2).compareTo(o2.substring(1, 2));`

Answer (score 0):

`out.nextToken().toString()` give you one string. Your array length should be 1, I presume.
Even if you put this into a loop, you sort at each loop, you have to sort outside the loop.

```
StringTokenizer out = new StringTokenizer( input.toString());
List<String> wordList = new ArrayList< String >();
while( out.hasMoreTokens()) {
    wordList.add( out.nextToken());
}
Collections.sort( wordList );
System.out.println(wordList.toString());
```